# Rails associations. How do they work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many

What is the exact purpose of associations?  I understand what the relationships mean and when to use each type for example:

```
belongs_to, has_many, has_one , has_and_belongs_to_many, ect
```

but i dont quite understand what purpose they serve in terms of how the connect things within rails. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're calling "associations" I would call "macros". That is, the `belongs_to`, `has_many` etc. macros are simply class methods being called on your ActiveRecord objects which, when called, define a bunch of functionality based on the association name.

So, what you're asking is: What functionality do these macro methods define? The answer for that lies within the Rails documentation for each of these methods:

- [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)
- [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)
- [has_one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)

And, even more, you should read the overall documentation on [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

But, in short, these macros define methods with names based on the association names you pass into them. So, for example:

```
belongs_to :my_object
```

Will define, as a greatly-simplified example:

```
def my_object
  MyObject.find_by_id(my_object_id)
end
```

So it's basically like metaprogramming your objects to have the methods needed to find the other, associated objects, update their collections, and so on.